# Django - nested relation query with the ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-related-manager

Because I need to avoid a recursive import and work with a `Group` object as my starting point for my query (which is why I can't import `Action` objects directly.)

The relationship is `Group` -> `Component` -> `ComponentVersion` -> `Action`

For instance, `Group.components.all()` returns all the components in a query set.

Additionally `[component.versions.all() for component in Group.components.all()]` returns a list of Querysets whose results are all of the versions. Subsequently, `.actions.all()` would return all the Queryset of `actions` for each `ComponentVersion` returned in the comprehension.

What is the optimal way to do this to avoid making unnecessary calls to the DB and for readability?

Answer (score 3):

[Prefetch Related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) start here, this will run 4 queries but will retrieve all the data right away vs iterating and making multiple queries.

```
Group.objects.all().prefetch_related('components', 'components__versions', 'components__versions__actions')
```

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, but how do i access the actual `actions` objects? i have something as you had mentioned, `component_qs = Group.components.all().prefetch_related('versions', 'versions__actions')`, so i can do `[component for component in component_qs]` and it returns a list of components as expected. if i for instance attempt `[component.versions.actions for component in component_qs]` i get `RelatedManager object has no attribute actions`

Comment: Yeah since versions is a related manager and not a action you would need to get one version actions at once. Component.versions()[0].actions. Or get the version whatever way you can, you might need to nest the list comprehensions, but at that point there might be more straightforward ways of doing it.